# These days SQL databases can store JSON. Then why do we need NoSQL?

Tags: sql, json, nosql

One of the advantages of NoSQL databases is to handle unstructured data. Since that issue is now resolved in SQL databases, is there any need left for NoSQL? Only advantage that I can think of is NoSQL is still better at scalability.

Comment: Is just the datatype that's deciding factor for you to go for NoSql?

Comment: @SMA it is the unstructured data that is deciding factor from my side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might choose a NoSQL database for the following reasons:

- To store large volumes of data that might have little to no
  structure.

  NoSQL databases do not limit the types of data that you can store
  together. NoSQL databases also enable you to add new data types as
  your needs change. With document-oriented databases, you can store
  data in one place without having to define the data type in advance.
- To make the most of cloud computing and storage.

  In order for a cloud solution to be scalable, the data must be easy
  to share across multiple servers.
- To speed development.

  When you are developing in rapid iterations or making frequent
  updates to the data structure, a relational database slows you down.
  However, because NoSQL data doesn’t need to be prepped ahead of time,
  you can make frequent updates to the data structure with minimal
  downtime.
- To boost horizontal scalability.

  The CAP (consistency, availability, and partition tolerance) theorem
  states that in any distributed system, only two of the three CAP
  properties can be used simultaneously. Adjusting these properties in
  favor of strong partition tolerance enables NoSQL users to boost
  horizontal scalability.

Comment: I don't agree, there was a benchmark (Postgres vs Mongo) - https://info.enterprisedb.com/rs/069-ALB-339/images/PostgreSQL_MongoDB_Benchmark-WhitepaperFinal.pdf; PostgreSQL completly outperform MongoDB in almost all key aspects. You can also have json and bson fields in databases like Postgres,so you can keep your data unstructured in PostgreSQL also (MySQL also have such option).

Answer (score 2):

The following Link provides sufficient details about the requirement of NoSQL databases.

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/reasons-to-use-a-nosql-db/

Comment: Link's server is not able to respond.

Comment: It's working for me and I have added reasons from there in another answer above. Please check and respond if it can help.